# Problems with Response.Redirect in ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect

I'm relatively new to ASP.NET and I'm having a problem with a simple web form.    I have a page that I need to redirect based on a result from a stored procedure.  I gather the userid (domain\name), compare to a MS SQL table to get a role for which report page to bring up (which will only bring back a single role such as Sales), then I want to redirect to a different aspx page based on the result.  I have a generic report link page with all reports for an admin role.  Then I have sales, marketing, custservice pages for reports that some users should only see.  I'm getting the role back since it is populating a textbox and a label, but I can't get it to redirect to the alternate pages.  Here is a copy of my code.  For now, I've commented out the "if else" redirects since they weren't working.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Configuration;

namespace MonogramFoods
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                //var username = User.Identity.Name;
                var username = "MSHOLDINGS\\efarney";

                SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection("server=mmsmv-sql1\\sql2008;database=Express;Trusted_Connection=True;");

                SqlDataAdapter MyDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SP_WEB_Check_User", MyConnection);

                MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40));

                MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@username"].Value = (username);

                MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userrole", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40));

                MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@userrole"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                DataSet DS = new DataSet();

                MyConnection.Open();

                MyDataAdapter.Fill(DS, "UsersRole");

                Session.Add("Role", DS);

                TextBox1.Text = MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[1].Value.ToString();

                Label1.Text = MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[1].Value.ToString();




                //if (TextBox1.Text == ("CustService"))
                //{
                //    Response.Redirect("ReportsMain_CS.aspx");
                //}
                //else if (TextBox1.Text == ("Marketing"))
                //{
                //    Response.Redirect("ReportsMain_MK.aspx");
                //}
                //else if (TextBox1.Text == ("Scorecard"))
                //{
                //    Response.Redirect("ReportsMain_SC.aspx");
                //}
                //else if (TextBox1.Text == ("Sales"))
                //{
                //    Response.Redirect("ReportsMain_SA.aspx");
                //}
                //else if (TextBox1.Text == ("Admin"))
                //{
                //    Response.Redirect("ReportsMain.aspx");

                //}

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In what way does it not work?  When you step through in a debugger, does `TextBox1.Text` have the value you expect?  As a side note, if you're redirecting immediately without ever displaying any user input, it would make more sense to store the value in a variable than in a page control.

Comment: Yes.  In the code, I'm using my login as the hard coded parameter, and it's pulling back the correct data.  Sales shows up in the Text1.Text and the Label1.Text.  All I'm wanting to do after that is to Code if the result is Sales, redirect to ReportsMain_SA.aspx.  From the user's perspective, when they click on the reports link (ReportsMain.aspx), and they're role is sales, they should immediately go to the ReportsMain_SA.aspx.  This is just a short term solution that I'm trying to put in for my manager since their was a last minute decision to limit the user's view of reports.

Comment: I've been working on this for a few days and I'm banging my head against a wall and really frustrated since I know this probably is a simple issue.

Comment: That's nice, but... You haven't actually explained how this isn't working.  `Response.Redirect()` should indeed redirect the user.  How is it failing?  When you step through this in a debugger, where/how *specifically* does this fail?

Comment: When I add in this code, it doesn't redirect the page.  It just opens up the ReportsMain.aspx page.

Comment: string userrole = null;

                username = TextBox1.Text;

                if (userrole == "Sales")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("ReportsMain_SA.aspx");
                }

Comment: Well, if you set `userrole` to `null` then why would you expect it to equal `"Sales"`?  An `if` condition must be true in order for the code within the `if` block to execute.

Comment: Sorry.  I was trying to set up the username, then in the next line, set it equal to the value of the TextBox.Text.  If I just set use string userrole = TextBox1.Text or userrole = "Sales", I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ".  Sorry, but my training has been learn as I go so far, so there's a lot I'm not aware of.

Comment: At the very least, can you show the actual code that's failing in your question and explain how it's failing?  Try to understand that nobody here can see your screen.  This guessing game format isn't going to work.  If you're getting a Null Reference Exception then Stack Overflow already has a pretty thorough and canonical answer that can be easily found.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be many things wrong in the point of view of an ASP.NET developper. Because you are are new, it is normal. You may want to change those things.

1. I think the redirect part on page load is wrong. This usually means you could have generated links based on the data of the SQL results in another page. Every post-back operation has a cost. The client needs to send back the whole form, including the ViewState which may be quite large. On mobile, this is unacceptable since people don't usually have an unlimited plan.
2. Please do not use the session storage. I mean ever. This is considered a bad practice nowaday because your application will not be able to scale horizontally. Also, putting a large structure of data in the Session is a bad idea, because every user will take a large clump of memory on the server. You may want to use a small Http-Only cookie instead to store roles for the current user. Please use POCO object (Plain Old CLR Objects) instead of a DataAdapter. This allows the data to be serialized (in JSON or XML for instance).
3. Use a variable to store data rather than a control that will never be shown. Again, this can be totally avoided by using a generated  tag on another page rather than doing a post-back.
4. You open a SQL connection, but you never close it. This can lead to memory leakage or to very large connection pools. Also close a connection that you open. You may use the `using` statement in order to not forget it.

Please see those points as area of improvements, not as critics.

Good luck.